# Program freezes when using RSA.ImportParameters() on android platform

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

Writing a Mobile App in Xamarin.Forms I'm using the RSA class (Security.Cryptography) to generate the base of an asymmetric encyption. Debugging the code for UWP I don't noticed any problems. But debugging the same code on a mobile phone (android) freezes the application when invoking the function ImportParameters.

A similar situation could be reproduced on the android emulator.

Here is the code snippet where the problem appears.

```cs
RSA_Private = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(3072);
RSA_Public = RSA.Create();
RSA_Public.ImportParameters(RSA_Private.ExportParameters(false));
```

The program has a problem to execute the last line of code and freezes there (don't execute further code). There doesn't appear any exception.

Is there a known issue with the way I use the RSA class? Or maybe it's not a problem of xamarin but an internal problem of the devices I use?

Comment: Did you try to use ` PCLCrypto library` in the xamarin forms? Here is a blog about it.https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4088a7/using-cryptography-in-portable-xamarin-formswindows-phone/ Or you can use dependence server to achieve it in android platform.https://dzone.com/articles/xamarin-android-asymmetric-encryption-without-any `System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates` this package did not exclaim it will suitable all mobile platform.

Comment: I had used PCLCryptoLibrary in one of my last projects, but now because of data stored almost on the server and the need to rewrite the code in many places I would avoid to implement another library. But if it's the easiest way I have to do it.

Comment: Tried with PCLCryptoLibrary and everything works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As "Leon Lu -MSFT" mentioned System.Security.Cryptography isn't prepared tu work on every mobile platform. There is the need of using another library like PCLCrypto Library.